# Python count drop in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'd like to count the number of time that the row of my Df are under a threshold.

I tried this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.ma.extras import _ezclump as ez

years = np.arange(2000, 2010)
engine = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Engine': np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 10),
'Year': np.tile(np.arange(2000, 2010), 2),
'Energy' : np.repeat([50,50,100,100,100,100,100,100,50,50,50,50,100,100,100,100,100,100,50,50], 1),
})

df = df.sort_values(['Engine','Year']).set_index('Year')    

Max = {'A':100,
'B':100}

df['Max']=df.Engine.map(Max)

df['ratio'] = df['Energy'] / df['Max']

df['interval'] = df['ratio'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x >= 0.80 else (1 if x < 0.80 and x >= 0.20 else 0        ))

engine_off = ez((df['interval'] == 1).to_numpy())
```

In my Df there are 4 drops.

But the real problem it's that in my engine_off, in the 2nd slice include the Engine A and B. So its count only 3 drops, not 4.

Someone now how I can do to fix this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "in my engine_off, in the 2nd slice include the Engine A and B". Could you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean it's if you count the number of drop by Engine you count 4 drops but this `engine_off = ez((df['interval'] == 1).to_numpy())` count only 3 drops because the ez function Finds the clumps.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: Thx it's that was I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to do it on each type of engine? Something like this:

```
engine_off_dict = {}
for name, frame in df.groupby('Engine'):
    engine_off = {name: ez((frame['interval'] == 1).to_numpy())}
    engine_off_dict.update(engine_off)
engine_off_dict

{'A': [slice(0, 2, None), slice(8, 10, None)],
 'B': [slice(0, 2, None), slice(8, 10, None)]}
```